# Impossible to pass job parameter to step scoped bean in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, late-binding

I'm writing a batch using Spring Batch and am trying to pass a job parameter to the item reader bean definition, but when I'm executing the batch I keep getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1027E:(pos 13): Indexing into type 'org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters' is not supported
```

Here is the code of the configuration class:

```
/**
 * Job producing an XML file aimed at synchronizing Appipay data with ForHRM data
 *
 * @author francois.dupire
 */
@Configuration
@Import(BatchConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = BusinessObjectServiceImpl.class)
public class ForHRMToAppipayDescriptiveDataSyncJobConfiguration {

    /*
     * Constants
     */
    public static final String JOB_NAME = "forHRMToAppipaySyncJob";
    private static final String FORHRM_TO_APPIPAY_SYNC_STEP = "forHRMToAppipaySyncStep";

    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 10;

    /*
     * Fields
     */
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    /*
     * Constructors
     */
    @Autowired
    public ForHRMToAppipayDescriptiveDataSyncJobConfiguration(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
    }

    /*
     * Job
     */
    @Bean
    public Job forHRMToAppipaySyncJob(Step forHRMToAppipaySyncStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get(JOB_NAME)
                .start(forHRMToAppipaySyncStep)
                .build();
        // TODO Add parameters validator
    }

    /*
     * Steps
     */
    // Sync step
    @Bean
    public Step forHRMToAppipaySyncStep(AppipaySyncTriggersReader reader, AppipaySyncTriggersToAppipayDescriptiveDataProcessor processor, AppipayDescriptiveDataWriter writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get(FORHRM_TO_APPIPAY_SYNC_STEP)
                .<List<SynchronisationAppipay>, Signaletiques>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public AppipaySyncTriggersReader appipaySyncTriggersReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['EMPCODE']}") String employerCode, SynchronisationAppipayRepository appipaySyncTriggerRepository) {
        return new AppipaySyncTriggersReader(employerCode, CHUNK_SIZE, appipaySyncTriggerRepository);
    }
```

I tried the following solutions:

- Use jobExecutionContext and stepExecutionContext instead of jobParameters. As a result I got null objects instead of passed parameters;
- Remove simple quote from around parameters name (e.g. #jobParameters[EMPCODE]), but then I got this error:

  ```
  Invalid property 'EMPCODE' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContext]: Bean property 'EMPCODE' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
  ```

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong because everything seems okay according to documentation and other posts I found browsing the net.

EDIT : I'm using Spring 4.3.3 and Spring Batch 3.0.7

Comment: What versions of Spring Framework and Spring Batch are you using?

Comment: Hi Michael. I'm using Spring 4.3.3 and Spring Batch 3.0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer to my question.

In BatchConfiguration, which I import into my configuration, there was a jobParameters bean which took precedence over the parameters that are passed to a job. So my arguments were not to be found in this bean. I removed it and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry maybe this isn't a good answer but it is too long for a comment.

I can't remember exactly how this all works, but I have a JobLauncherDetails class that is basically just the provided example.

I think the key is that SOMEONE has to implement the JobLauncherDetails class -- mine extends QuartzJobBean.  But one way or another someone has to retrieve this data from the spring-batch BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS table.  I think that might be what you are missing.

Anyhow this is the code in case it helps you

```
public class JobLauncherDetails extends QuartzJobBean {

/**
 * Special key in job data map for the name of a job to run.
 */
static final String JOB_NAME = "jobName";

static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
{
    String threadId = String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    ThreadContext.put("TId", threadId);
}

private JobLocator jobLocator;

private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

/**
 * Public setter for the {@link JobLocator}.
 * @param jobLocator the {@link JobLocator} to set
 */
public void setJobLocator(JobLocator jobLocator) {
    this.jobLocator = jobLocator;
}

/**
 * Public setter for the {@link JobLauncher}.
 * @param jobLauncher the {@link JobLauncher} to set
 */
public void setJobLauncher(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
    this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
}



/*
 * Copy parameters that are of the correct type over to
 * {@link JobParameters}, ignoring jobName.
 *
 * @return a {@link JobParameters} instance
 */
private JobParameters getJobParametersFromJobMap(Map<String, Object> jobDataMap) {

    JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();

    for (Entry<String, Object> entry : jobDataMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (value instanceof String && !key.equals(JOB_NAME)) {
            builder.addString(key, (String) value);
        }
        else if (value instanceof Float || value instanceof Double) {
            builder.addDouble(key, ((Number) value).doubleValue());
        }
        else if (value instanceof Integer || value instanceof Long) {
            builder.addLong(key, ((Number)value).longValue());
        }
        else if (value instanceof Date) {
            builder.addDate(key, (Date) value);
        }
        else {
            logger.debug("JobDataMap contains values which are not job parameters (ignoring).");
        }
    }

    return builder.toJobParameters();

}


@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws org.quartz.JobExecutionException {
    Map<String, Object> jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.getMergedJobDataMap();
    String jobName = (String) jobDataMap.get(JOB_NAME);
    logger.info("Quartz trigger firing with Spring Batch jobName="+jobName);
    JobParameters jobParameters = getJobParametersFromJobMap(jobDataMap);
    try {
        jobLauncher.run(jobLocator.getJob(jobName), jobParameters);
    }
    catch (JobExecutionException e) {
        logger.error("Could not execute job.", e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Terry,

Thanks for your answer. Though I'm not sure I understand what the problem in my configuration is and what you propose to solve it?

I should be able to pass job parameters using @Value. And if not possible I still could implement a listener in the concerned bean to provide them with the wanted parameters (though it would be less pretty :-/)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on OP's answer: Apparently, when you want to access job parameters in Spring Batch, you always have to refer to them as `jobParameters`.

The instance that contains your passed-in parameters is automatically defined by the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation (much like `jobLauncher` or `jobBuilders`). Hence, declaring a bean named `jobParameters` in your configuration will cause a conflict with the already declared bean of the same name, leading to compile errors.

To avoid this, declare your parameters either outside of the configuration, or name your bean differently, e.g. `jobParams`.